# Vuetable not registering <vuetable-field-component:account-details> when using __component:account-details

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

Using Vuetable-2 with laravel but keep getting the error

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <vuetable-field-component:account-details> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

For both the the account-details and account-actions components.

Even though i have already registered the components. Here is the code.

```
// TableAccounts.vue

<template>
    <base-vuetable :api-url="route" :fields="fields" :sort-order="sortOrder">
    </base-vuetable>
</template>
<script>
import BaseVuetable from './BaseVuetable.vue';
import AccountActions from './AccountActions.vue';
import AccountDetails from './AccountDetails.vue';

Vue.component('account-actions', require('./AccountActions.vue').default);
Vue.component('account-details', require('./AccountDetails.vue').default);

let fields = [
                {
                  name: '__component:account-details',
                  title: '',
                },
                {
                  name: 'email',
                  title: 'Email',
                  sortField: 'email',
                  callback: (value) => this.email(value)
                },
                {
                  name: 'fullname',
                  title: 'Fullname',
                  sortField: 'fullname'
                },
                {
                  name: 'company',
                  title: 'Company',
                  sortField: 'company',

                },
                {
                  name: 'role_name',
                  title: 'Role',
                  sortField: 'type'
                },
                {
                  name: 'active',
                  title: 'Status',
                  sortField: 'active',
                  callback: (value) => this.active(value)
                },
                {
                  name: 'signed_in_at',
                  title: 'Last Login',
                  sortField: 'signed_in_at',
                  callback: (value) => this.fromNow(value)
                },
                {
                  name: 'updated_at',
                  title: 'Last update',
                  sortField: 'updated_at',
                  callback: (value) => this.fromNow(value)
                },
                {
                    titleClass: 'account__actions-button',
                    name: '__component:account-actions',
                    title: '',
                }
            ]

export default {
    components: {
        BaseVuetable,
        AccountActions,
        AccountDetails
    },
    props: {
        route: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            fields,
            sortOrder: [
                {
                    field: 'updated_at',
                    sortField: 'updated_at',
                    direction: 'desc'
                }
            ],
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Any idea why? I have even registred the components globally. If i debug the global components they are there.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are registering components globally(with Vue.component()), as well as locally(with components: {})? I would delete the global registration.

Comment: @RussDeneychuk no, i have tried both ways, with just locally registered, globally, or both.. doesn't seem to make a diference